# What is the Difference between the dotnet and dotnet5.x monikers?

Tags: .net, dnx, .net-core

What is the difference between the `dotnet` moniker and a `dotnet5.2` or `dotnet5.3` moniker in the `ref` (references) folder? Why do some of the NuGet packages have just `dotnet` and then others have multiple versioned monikers?

[image: System.Runtime.InteropServices]

[image: System.Linq]

[image: System.Reflection]

Comment: They are called ".Net Generations" ... but they are undocumented. David Fowler of the ASP.Net 5 team promised an upcoming article 3 days ago.

Comment: https://github.com/davidfowl/aspnetvnextwebapiapp/blob/master/Generations.md is the latest documentation on Generations. "dotnet" without the version number means that you need to reference the individual contracts instead of the contracts in the generation. Or something like that. :)

Answer (score 2):

#### What is the difference between the `dotnet` moniker and a `dotnet5.2` or `dotnet5.3` moniker in the `ref` folder?

What is being talked about is called the [.NET Standard Platform](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/project-docs/standard-platform.md).

Everything that is under `ref` folder is basically just a *contract* assembly with no real implementation to make it easier to find what you can depend on or not. Once your assembly hit the real platform, it can depend on the real assembly since it's all its contracts are identical to the `ref` one that was supplied.

#### Why do some of the NuGet packages have just dotnet and then others have multiple versioned monikers?

Yet again, the .NET Standard Platform. I would go on a limb here and say that a few of those might just be tests by the team.